# Trying to execute .exe from std::cout

Tags: c++, std

I have a C++ program that reads a config file and gets the directories.
What I want to do now is to execute an .exe program using the directory settings from the config file.

Here is a piece of my code:

```
int main(){

ConfigFile cfg("htbaseconfig.properties");

bool exists = cfg.keyExists("backuplocation");
exists = cfg.keyExists("logdir");
exists = cfg.keyExists("execdir");
exists = cfg.keyExists("fulldir");
exists = cfg.keyExists("incdir");
exists = cfg.keyExists("appdir");

std::string bkploc = cfg.getValueOfKey<std::string>("backuplocation");
std::cout << "Backup Location: " << bkploc << "\n";

std::string bkplogdir = cfg.getValueOfKey<std::string>("logdir");
std::cout << "Log Location: " << bkplogdir << "\n";

std::string bkpexec = cfg.getValueOfKey<std::string>("execdir");
std::cout << "Exec Directory: " << bkpexec << "\n";

std::string bkpfulldir = cfg.getValueOfKey<std::string>("fulldir");
std::cout << "Full Directory: " << bkpfulldir << "\n";

std::string bkpappdir = cfg.getValueOfKey<std::string>("appdir");
std::cout << "Real app Directory: " << bkpappdir << "\n\n\n";

for( ; ; ) {

Sleep(6000);

ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", , L"C:\\teste.htm", NULL,SW_SHOWNORMAL);

}

std::cin.get();
return (0);}
```

Inside the ShellExecute, I wanted to execute the following line parsing the config options:

```
$execdir/program.exe $logdir/log.txt $bkpappdir $bkploc
```

How do I do this? I want to execute my program with the variables I get on `std::cout`.

Comment: `std::string`s can be concatenated, though you're going to run into trouble in that you really need to be working with `std::wstring`s.

Answer (score 1):

You must pass to ShellExecute, instead of the second NULL, a string (c string, a char[]) that contains all parameters, like if you are passing them to the command line.

So Will be something like

```
ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", , L"C:\\teste.htm", "option=param option2=param2",SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Depends on how you parse them (or how they are parsed) from the other exe file